# How to put all even numbers in order first appear, and then odd numbers appear?

Tags: java, arrays

I having problem is how rearrange an array of int values so that all the even
values appear before all the odd values . Below is my coding:

```
   import java.io.*; 

  public class EvenAppearBeforeOdd {
// function to rearrange the array in given way. 
static void rearrangeEvenAndOdd(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    // variables 
    int j = -1,temp; 

    // quick sort method 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

        // if array of element 
        // is odd then swap 
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) { 

            // increment j by one 
            j++; 

            // swap the element 
            temp = arr[i]; 
            arr[i] = arr[j]; 
            arr[j] = temp; 
        } 
    } 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 15, 9, 1, 3, 10, 5, 4, 8 }; 
    System.out.println("\n\nBefore\n");
    System.out.println(arr[]);
     try {
        System.out.println(EvenAppearBeforeOdd.rearrangeEvenAndOdd(arr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!!!");
   }
    int n = arr.length; 

    rearrangeEvenAndOdd(arr, n); 
  System.out.println("\n\nAfter\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
} 
  }
```

The error output show in the below:

```
  run:
  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: 
  Cancelled by user.
  BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Actually I want the output like the below:

```
  run:


  Before

  15 9 1 3 10 5 4 8 


  After

  10 4 8 3 15 5 9 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Hope anyone can help me check the coding which part I wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: how swap will solve the problem? should be shift and linked list is there for it if there is not such bound and your problem statement seems not right tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below is the answer that produces the result matching your sample input and output:

```
public class EvenAppearBeforeOdd {    
    static void rearrangeEvenAndOdd(int arr[]) {
        int j = 0, temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    static void printArray(int arr[]) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+"\t");
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = { 15, 9, 1, 3, 10, 5, 4, 8 };
        System.out.println("Before:");
        printArray(arr);
        rearrangeEvenAndOdd(arr);
        System.out.println("After:");
        printArray(arr);
    }
}
```

You can compare your answer with it and easily find the mistake. Feel free to comment if you still have any issue.

**Update [06-Oct-2019 19:00]:**

To solve the issue raised by WJS, `rearrangeEvenAndOdd` method can be written as:

```
static void rearrangeEvenAndOdd(int arr[]) {
    int j, temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            temp = arr[i];
            j=i-1;
            while(j>=0 && arr[j]%2==1) {
                arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it will not produce the result matching your sample input and output i.e. for the input array as { 15, 9, 1, 3, 10, 5, 4, 8 }, the result would be produced as {10, 4, 8, 15, 9, 1, 3, 5} and not as your sample output which is {10, 4, 8, 3, 15, 5, 9, 1}.

Comment: If need to check for any possible errors and throw an exception, which part I should insert the code? I mean using catch (Exception e)

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. Just only I want to catch possible errors and throw an exception. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me to add code for catch possible errors and throw an exception? Because my doing project  need it.

Comment: catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!!!");  //this code

Comment: Your method fails for  `int[] arr = { 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9
   };`

Comment: The OP said the values should remain in the order that they appear with even in front and odd in back.  The example I  showed had  1,3, 9 and after your algorithm it was 3,1, 9.

Answer (score 1):

If you are bound by a requirement to not use any additional memory in your algorithm, then we would have to find a way to fix your current approach.  I think the conceptually easiest approach is to use a duplicate empty array to build the output.  First, iterate the input array and copy over all even values.  Then, iterate again and copy over all odd values.

```
static int[] rearrangeEvenAndOdd(int arr[], int n) {
    int[] output = new int[n];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) output[count++] = arr[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) output[count++] = arr[i];
    }

    return output;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 15, 9, 1, 3, 10, 5, 4, 8 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    arr = rearrangeEvenAndOdd(arr, arr.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

This prints:

```
[15, 9, 1, 3, 10, 5, 4, 8]
[10, 4, 8, 15, 9, 1, 3, 5]
```

Note that this is a linear solution, requiring two full scans of the input array, and it also requires twice the storage of the input.

Comment: But why cannot find "array" symbol?

Comment: Mr Tim Biegeleisen. Can you send the demo again? Because your link are Requested page not found.

Comment: If need to check for any possible errors and throw an exception, which part I should code? Can you guide me?

Comment: I mean using catch (Exception e)

Comment: The code I wrote doesn't really throw any checked exceptions, so I wouldn't check for exceptions under normal conditions.

Comment: Ok. Let me check first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seem wrong.

Not sure if it were a errata, but you should try compiling in the editor (eclipse).

It will show all errors and warning about the syntax.

```
System.out.println(arr[]);
System.out.println(EvenAppearBeforeOdd.rearrangeEvenAndOdd(arr);
```